# sql инъекция в запросах

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

Получаю гет запросом логин и отправляю его в `sql` запрос

```
    @app.route('/api/login' )
    def login():
    
        login = request.args.get("l")
        with connect(host=host,user=user,password=pa,database=db) as connection:
                select_movies_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = '" + login + "'"
    
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(select_movies_query)
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    for row in result:
                         print(row)
```

При данной схеме возникает возможность sql инъекций. Подскажите, какие есть способы,что бы игнорировать `'` в запросах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте связываемые переменные - это обезопасит вас от `SQL Injections`:

```
select_movies_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = %s"
...
cursor.execute(select_movies_query, [login])
```

Функция `cursor.execute(query, parameters)` в качестве второго параметра ожидает кортеж или список значений, которые будут подставляться вместо `%s` в запросе. Подставление делается по порядку - вместо первого `%s` подставляется первый элемент из `parameters` и т.д.

**NOTE:** обратите внимание, что в запросе отсутствуют кавычки вокруг строкового литерала - БД драйвер сам позаботиться об этом.

Comment: А разве в MySQL не `:s` местозаменители, или flask предварительно заменит?

Comment: @0xdb, в драйвере [PyMysql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) поддерживаются два стиля параметров: `%s` и `%(name)s`. Во втором случае надо передавать словарь, в котором ключи соответствуют именам переменных